# How to tell Apache Tomcat who must handle received data?

Tags: tomcat, server, war, web-deployment, catalina

I'm using the newest Apache Tomcat (9.0.16), with newest Java / OpenSSL. I got a WAR file with a server application from NEXUSe2e.org.

I'm able to send a secure message to a service. After a while someone sends a secure reply message as a new https message.

In the logging, I can see that this message is decrypted by TomCat. It is detected that this is a new `SOAP action: ebXML`.

This is done, using the following connectors in file `%catalina_home%\conf\server.xml`

```
<Connector
  port="443"
  protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
  redirectPort="8443"/>

<Connector
  port="8443"
  protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"

  SSLEnabled="true"
  secure="true"
  scheme="https"

  defaultSSLHostConfigName="_default_">
  <SSLHostConfig 
    hostName="_default_"
    certificateVerification="required"

    <Certificate
      certificateChainFile="conf\Certificates\TrustedCertificates.pem"
      certificateFile="conf\Certificates\... .crt"
      certificateKeyFile="conf\Certificates\... .private.key"/>
  </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>
```

When the data has been correctly decrypted, it has to go to my server code (NEXUSe2e). How does TomCat know who must handle the data?

- Does TomCat actively send the received data to the server. Is it somewhere in the configuration file who is expecting the data?
- Is the server regularly polling to see if data has been received?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomcat knows which application will handle your request by looking at the URL you have requested, and check if there is any [context](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html) matching. There is no waiting or polling, things are chained automatically.

In your case you are just copying a war file in the webapps directory, this is called [Automatic Application Deployment](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/host.html#Automatic_Application_Deployment). There are other ways to configure a context but it's nice to keep things simple while it is sufficient.

Things are a little bit more complicated if you are using Virtual Hosts, as Tomcat would start by checking what domain name you requested, and then check which context is concerned.